# Venn diagram for $A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have searched through my math books and online and been unable to find a Venn diagram for two identical sets.
In other words  $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$. 
Can a single Venn diagram show both conditions simultaneously?

Comment: Just a single circle which is labelled both A and B

Comment: Use `$A \subset B$` for $A \subset B$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to just labelling the same circle both $A$ and $B$, you could perhaps annotate $\emptyset$ (empty set) into the non overlapping portions of $A$ and $B$:

[image: Venn AeqB]

Comment: True.  But as empty sets are... empty.... it could be argued it'd be clearer if they weren't depicted as having substance. I'm not sure what this diagram gains that a single circle wouldn't demonstrate.  It's a good OP question but the question reflects confusion which this simply compounds upon.

Comment: Well, I could imagine that sets $A$ and $B$ have been specified differently, and the fact of their equality was a somewhat unexpected outcome. Then separate circles would then reflect that original variation in specification. However equally there are plenty of circumstances where labelling a single circle with both $A$ and $B$ (or perhaps with $A=B$) would be clearer.